# How do I use non-"legacy" launchctl commands to load and unload plists?

Tags: macos, command-line, launchd, development, startup

I have some plist files in `~/Library/LaunchAgents`.

I have been happily using `launchctl load -w` and `launchctl unload -w` to turn these on and off for years.  However, I notice that now `load` and `unload` are relegated to the "legacy" section of the man page.  Let's call one of them `com.example.service.plist`.

However, when I try to interact with these plists via `launchctl enable "gui/$(id -u)/com.example.service"` and `launchctl disable "gui/$(id -u)/com.example.service"`, other launchd commands *seem* to report success - for example, `launchctl print "gui/$(id -u)"` totally shows me disabled flags that correspond to the state that I've set - the services don't actually start and stop or listen and unlisten on their ports.

Is there some step I'm missing?  For the moment I am sticking with `load` and `unload` but I'd like to learn the non-deprecated way of interacting with this stuff before Apple eventually slams the door on the old/bad way...

Comment: The legacy means that a change is afoot - you can still use load and unload to your heart's content on 10.11 and lower. My presumption is Apple will have documentation at WWDC this year and a timeline for migration...

Comment: I guess there just might not be an answer for this yet, but it sure *looks* like `enable` and `disable` are intended to replace `load` and `unload`.  I just can't get them to work as I expect.

Comment: Have you tried following `launchctl enable` with `launchctl kickstart`?

Comment: I have not, but isn't `launchctl kickstart` supposed to just issue an activation for the job in question?  I am using launchd specifically because I want purely on-demand activation.

Comment: This looks like it may help: https://babodee.wordpress.com/2016/04/09/launchctl-2-0-syntax/

Answer (score 8):

[I asked](https://twitter.com/tjluoma/status/720627400883728384) the Twitter user [@launchderp](https://twitter.com/launchderp):

> @launchderp Are`launchctl load` and unload still safe to use, at least until 10.12 or whatever comes next?
>
> c.f [How do I use non-"legacy" launchctl commands to load and unload plists?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/226253/how-do-i-use-non-legacy-launchctl-commands-to-load-and-unload-plists)

And [@launchderp replied](https://twitter.com/launchderp/status/720628647976042496)

> @tjluoma Yeah they're still safe. Too many years of dependencies to break them.

While this may not seem like an official Apple statement, I believe this person to be someone who is actively working on `launchd` for Apple, and trust what they say. YMMV.

**Moral of the story: If load/unload is working for you, keep using them :-)**

Comment: Not marking as "accepted" because it doesn't quite address the question about `enable` and `disable` but upvoted because I still appreciate the information :).

Comment: I asked a follow-up question because load/unload stopped working for me, and I don't know why: https://twitter.com/heathborders/status/1480954665680269320

Answer (score 6):

[The article](https://babodee.wordpress.com/2016/04/09/launchctl-2-0-syntax/) referred by TJ Luoma is very helpful. Steps for Launch Daemon:

1. Save your plist file in `/Library/LaunchDaemons/` as usual. Let's say the file is `com.example.mysrv.plist`, and the Label in plist is `com.example.mysrv`.
2. `sudo launchctl bootstrap system /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.example.mysrv.plist`. Note that the path can be relative (to `$PWD`) or absolute.
3. Check the service with `sudo launchctl print system/com.example.mysrv`. It should say "running".

Launch Agents should be similar. Caveat: I have no idea how to stop a service without unloading it through `bootout`.